# DIY Ozone Generator: difference using plate-based or tube-based solution for corona effect?

Tags: high-voltage, ozone

I wanna build an ozone generator to use to sanitize object, cloths and so on.
Searching on internet I found two main solutions:

1. **Plate Based** (or in some cases based on very sharp nails or pins)

[image]

2. **Tube based**
   [image]

As far I understand right now, both solutions work with an high voltage (HV) tension around 3KV or 4KV and are based on corona effect, but the tube method seems better in terms of O3 quantity generated.

About the solution (2), I found a video on YouTube where the makers use a neon/fluorescent tube instead of plastic tube. In the video they explain as "inner conductor" it's better to use an ionized gas, instead of another metallic mesh, to maximize the efficiency. 
So to build it they wrap the neon tube with a metallic mesh, then connect one wire of the HV geneator to the neon tube pin and the other one to the metallic mesh around the tube.

Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFMKA1MgyGw

I'm a bit confused about that, so I would ask you: which solution is better to implement to maximize the power consumption/ozone generated ratio? And in case of the neon tube how long should it be?

Comment: Please post a link to the video.

Comment: That's not a neon tube.  It's a fluorescent light tube.  It's easier to build.  I'm not convinced that it is in any other way better than the other design.